# Factor table of features in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, data-science

I have dataframe within that I have columns StudentInquiryCategory studentProgram and Enrollment, enollment has values 0 and 1, StudentInquirCategory has Inquiry souces and StudentProgram has Courses I want to create factor table like this

| StudentInquirycategory | Search | Website | Field | Email/Social |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| StudentProgramType |  |  |  |  |
| MEd | 0.25 | 0.36 | 0.21 | 0.11 |
| NonDegree | 0.66 | 0.22 | 0.35 | 0.79 |
| Certificate | 0.45 | 0.21 | 0.58 | 0.32 |
| E.D | 0.75 | 0.65 | 0.28 | 0.97 |

#code

```
ProgramEnRate = []

InqcatEnRate = []

data_dict = dict()

df_fact = pd.DataFrame()

def Program_Shape(Program, Category):

    for p in Program:
        ProgramtypeEn = df1[(df1["ProgramType"] == (p)) & (df1["Enrolled"] == 1)]
        Programtype = df1[df1["ProgramType"] == (p)]
        PrEn = ProgramtypeEn.shape[0]
        PrType = Programtype.shape[0]
        if PrEn != 0:
            res = (PrEn/PrType)
        else:
            res = 0        
        for c in Category:
            Inqcat = ProgramtypeEn[ProgramtypeEn["InquiryCategory"] == (c)]
            if Inqcat.shape[0] != 0:
                res1 = Inqcat.shape[0]/PrEn
            else:
                res1 = 0
            InqcatEnRate.append(res1)
            if (res1 != 0) or (res != 0):
                InqCatres = res1/res
            else:
                InqCatres = 0
        ProgramEnRate.append(res)
    print("ProgramType: ", ProgramEnRate)
    print("InquiryCategory: ",InqcatEnRate)
Program_Shape(rows, cols)

'''
#cols
array(['cpc', 'direct', 'manual-entry', 'paid-social', 'email',
       'referral', 'field', nan, 'display', 'Partner', 'Website',
       'social', 'Search', 'organic', 'Email/Social/Alum', 'test', 'Test',
       'Media', 'historical', 'Other', 'Aggregate', 'Affiliate', 'ESA',
       'video', 'website'], dtype=object)

#rows
array(['Masters of Education (M.Ed.)', 'Non-Degree', 'Certificate',
       'Doctorate - Ed.D.', nan, 'Bachelor of Science - B.S.',
       'Masters of Arts (M.A.)', 'Master of Science in Nursing (MSN)',
       'Doctorate - Ed.S.', 'Transition to Teaching (T2T)', 'Doctorate'],
      dtype=object)
I have created code but no success
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible problem set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and all relevant code necessary to reproduce the example.  In addition, please explain the desired output table and the logic employed to achieve this table.

Comment: cols = df1["StudentInquiryCategory"].unique()
rows = df1["ProgramType"].unique()

Comment: current output:
ProgramType:  [0.4162686183872625, 0.25177887246852765, 0.26449864498644987, 0.32687334046001587, 0, 0.2242798353909465, 0.17237982663514578, 0.10719023613690634, 0.21862052156958323, 0.24397824397824397, 0.20610687022900764]
InquiryCategory:  [0.04818162188839878, 0.6034424257379931, 0.013356365094543323, 0.0004626916314506925, 0.001357228785588698, 0.004102532465529473, 0.06468429007680682, 0, 0.000123384435053518, 0.0013880748943520774, 0.05832999167155063, 0.0001542305438168975, 0.0010549636037556704, 0.0819706720118156]

Comment: Please edit your question and post your output as code within the question, so that it is readable.  See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") for an example of how to do this.